# Efficient way to handle/define the array of struct pollfd for poll syscall

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, polling

I am using poll for implementing the server side of a client-server model with multiplexing.

There's a main loop that the server is running.
In each loop I am checking all the fds at the array of struct pollfd until I find `n` sockets that have content for me (where `n` is the number that poll returned).
*Also, poll is used without timeout (-1 as argument).*

So if a new connection is requested at the listening socket I am inserting the socket and some client information into a active connections list I am keeping.

What is the most efficient way to handle the array of poll?

Should I define a small array of size 10 and if there are more clients re allocate memory for an array of size 20 or 50?

Or should I: (a) free the array of struct pollfd type, and (b) reallocate it with size that is equal to the size of the list(+1 for the listening socket) => every time a client closes a connection (and thus I have to remove an element from the array (probably setting the socket to -1, so that poll ignores it) resulting in unused space in array)

What do you recommend?

Thank you for your time

---

**Edit:**
I think I've found a solution with realloc and shifting with memmove each time a client disconnects to cover his socket at the fds array.

Comment: I think we need more info. 1. How many clients are you expecting to handle simultaneously, at the most? Is it *a large number* (eg. 10,000)? 2. How often do clients connect/disconnect? What are their patterns? Do they open a connection, they send a command, recieve a response and then immediately disconnect?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: 1. Not many, since it's an assignment. The client probably will complete his work in approximately 5 minutes. No, there is some more interaction, since it is a file synchronisation application. I've though of something, please look at the update.

Comment: Is your program required to meet specific performance criteria? If so, please provide that criteria and evidence that `poll` is the most significant bottleneck in your application (eg. using a profiler).

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: It should be generally fast (that's why we are using multiplexing with a thread pool) but other that nothing else. They just told me that the server shouldn't have wasted space (if I allocated an array of size 1024 for example).

Comment: I would argue that a design involving *thread pools* to handle a mere 50 clients is far more wasteful than a design involving a fixed size array of 50 `struct pollfd`s. I'd be considering using a profiler to determine which is the best place to expose concurrency at, too. Is it 50, or 1024? How many is "not many"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the most efficient way to handle the array of poll?

Implementation-defined. Don't optimise until you know you have to; That's called premature optimisation, and it's a waste of time.

> Should I define a small array of size 10 and if there are more clients
>   re allocate memory for an array of size 20 or 50?

If your profiler determines that your `pollfd`s are a significant bottleneck in your program, and your boss (or professor) says your program "*isn't fast enough*", go for it. If the largest your list will get is 50, then just use a static array, set the `fd` members to `-1`, don't bother shifting things around when you remove from the array... The bottlenecks you're referring to will be insignificant for such a small number.

If you're trying to handle much larger numbers of clients as a worst case, you might be concerned about unused space trailing the array when handling smaller numbers... and hence would choose a resizable `pollfd` array.

> Or should I: (a) free the array of struct pollfd type, and (b)
>   reallocate it with size that is equal to the size of the list(+1 for
>   the listening socket) => every time a client closes a connection (and
>   thus I have to remove an element from the array (probably setting the
>   socket to -1, so that poll ignores it) resulting in unused space in
>   array)

The simplest algorithm I can think of doubles space on resizing. Perhaps the most significant benefit to doubling on resize is the reduction in calls to `realloc` compared to linear resizing; Rather than accepting 1024 connections and calling `realloc` 1024 times, I'd prefer to accept 1024 connections and call `realloc` 10 or 11 times. It also seems simpler to me because there is no need to store the array capacity separately to the used count; You can use a property of binary numbers to your advantage: `(n - 1) & n == 0` when `n` is a power of two.

```
#define is_power_of_two(n) !(((n) - 1) & (n))

struct pollfd *pollfd_array_resize(struct pollfd *array, size_t size) {
    const size_t max_size = SIZE_MAX / sizeof *array;
    if (size == max_size) { return NULL; }
    if (is_power_of_two(size)) {
        array = realloc(array, (size > 0 ? size * 2 : 1) * sizeof *array);
    }
    return array;
}
```

> **Edit:** I think I've found a solution with realloc and shifting with memmove each time a client disconnects to cover his socket at the fds
>   array.

That seems like a fairly good fix. It increases cache locality, but at the cost of having to call `memmove` and `realloc` every time a client disconnects.

I wouldn't even consider "defragmenting" the array until my profiler indicates that `poll` is using up too much processor time. When that happens, I'd consider setting the `fd` member to something negative (as you *were* doing prior to your edit) and putting the index of the item to remove into a `recently_freed` stack. When inserting, I'd choose items from that stack if possible. If you must defragment, I suggest doing so based upon the size of that stack.

```
size_t pollfd_array_defrag(struct pollfd *array, size_t size) {
    size_t new_size = 0;
    for (size_t x = 0; x + 1 < size; x++) {
        if (array[x].fd < 0) {
            continue;
        }

        array[new_size++] = array[x];
    }
    return new_size;
}

int main(void) {
    size_t size = 0, index;
    struct pollfd *array = NULL;
    struct index_stack *recently_freed = NULL;

    /*----------------------------*
     * ... snip for insertion ... */
    if (recently_freed && recently_freed->size > 0) {
        index = index_stack_pop(&recently_freed);
    }
    else {
        struct pollfd *temp = pollfd_array_resize(array, size);

        if (temp == NULL) {
            /* TODO: Handle memory allocation errors */
        }

        array = temp;
        index = size++;
    }

    array[index] = (struct pollfd) { .fd = your_fd,
                                     .events = your_events,
                                     .revents = your_revents };

    /*--------------------------*
     * ... snip for removal ... */
    index_stack_push(&recently_freed, index);
    array[index] = -1;

    /*----------------------------------*
     * ... snip for defragmentation ... */
    if (is_power_of_two(recently_freed->size) && recently_freed->size * 2 + 1 > size) {
        size = pollfd_array_defrag(array);
        /* array will shrink in future insertions */
        index_stack_destroy(&recently_freed);
        recently_freed = NULL;
    }
}
```